# URL works in browser and Postman but not in cURL

Tags: php, php-curl

I'm all out of ideas with this one. Its a simple curl request and its not working. The URL is

```
https://www.nseindia.com/api/event-calendar?index=equities&from_date=05-05-2020&to_date=05-05-2020
```

It works fine in browser. I put it into Postman, simple GET request and it works there as well. I generate PHP code from postman itself and it doesn't work. The code keeps running until timeout and then I get a 500 internal server error. In the Apache logs I get this

```
[Mon May 04 18:47:59.325513 2020] [fcgid:warn] [pid 25143] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 112.196.159.208:47585] mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server
[Mon May 04 18:47:59.325568 2020] [core:error] [pid 25143] [client 112.196.159.208:47585] End of script output before headers: test.php
```

I also created this [playground](https://www.tehplayground.com/Nbe7RPeBfoY4bEvn) to make sure the problem is not my server but same result.

Why is it not working in cURL?

Comment: They probably block non-browser clients.

Answer (score 0):

As @Evert mentioned, they block non browser request, so you could trick your request by appending a `User-Agent` with the key : `CURLOPT_USERAGENT`

```php
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_USERAGENT   => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0",
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.nseindia.com/api/event-calendar?index=equities&from_date=05-05-2020&to_date=05-05-2020",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$error = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);

if($error) {
    echo "cURL Error:" . $error;
} else {
    echo $response;
}
```

Comment: Is that working for you? Its not working for me. And how would postman be working? Its not even adding any headers.

Comment: yes it works locally by executing this file. I'm not sure for Postman but whey I make a `curl https://...` I get an Access Denied but with `curl -A "" https://...` it works ( `-A` adding a user agent to a curl request) so it's weird it works but just with a blank `User-Agent` and Postman or Insomnia are adding it I think.

Comment: No. Its not working for me. Is this working for you? https://www.tehplayground.com/JiXStmvlUwmzZIzQ

Comment: Did you try it on your machine ?

Comment: Yes. I tried curl command in SSH, on my webpage where I need it and on the playground. Its not working anywhere. Here's the url where this api is being used if that helps. Check network tab of developer tools. https://www.nseindia.com/companies-listing/corporate-filings-event-calendar